# Tikzexternalize not creating pdf

Tags: compiling, tikz-external

I'm using `tikzexternalize` but somehow it stopped working all of a sudden. If I use the option `tikzexternalize[optimize=false]` it compiles like forever (10 hours last time I checked), but seems to work..

I'm using the option `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,up to date check=md5, force remake]`

I actually can't recreate this problem in a simple way.

Log of Master

```
 ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
    rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/Master_diplom-figure0" "\def\tikzext
    ernalrealjob{Master_diplom}\input{Master_diplom}"' did NOT result in a usable o
    utput file 'tikz/Master_diplom-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:)
    . Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdfl
    atex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like th
    at. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/Ma
    ster_diplom-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

Log of a Picture:

```
 The command '\includegraphics [width=\linewidth ,height=0.6\linewidth ]{MPCcomb
    in.tikz}' has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disab
    le this.

LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.
  ))

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'tikz/Master_diplom-figure1', but it seems th
ere is no such image in the document!?  
   You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can ha
ppen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a
 \label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to 
the main aux file.
   Possible solutions in this case:
   (a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
   (b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error
 -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/Master_diplom-figure1" "\def\tikzexterna
lrealjob{Master_diplom}\input{Master_diplom}"' *manually* (also check the prece
eding externalized images, perhaps the file name sequence is not correct).
   Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: Make sure that all your tikz drawings are correct, `tikzexternalize` sometimes does not properly transfer errors in the `tikz` drawing to the console. The first error looks like what you get when you have a mistake in your `tikz` code, what does it say when you ask to continue? Using `force remake` jeopardises the use of `tikzexternalize` as it just draws every picture again each compilation, see section 50.4.3 of the pgf manual.

Comment: I've made some Plots using Matlab2Tikz. I dont know if theres a Proble with them. I can't continue the process. It seems to try to create the pdf but stops and goes over to the next picture. Trying `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,up to date check=md5, optimize=false]` now